# Computer Isn't Detecting Sony Headphones Microphone

Tags: microphone, headphones

[image]I have a pair of WH-1000XM4 headphones that when I connect to the computer it does not detect the Microphone. The output is perfectly fine but for input there is no option to select the WH-1000XM4 headphones. It works fine when I connect to my phone. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: I am confused, WH-1000XM4, is listed in the input list shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Your computer is "detecting" the mic, else it would not be in the list of Input Devices. But it, or this specific application, is not allowing it or considers it inactive or incompatible or something else. What application is this? Have you tested using different applications? Have you run the OS' audio troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

The BlueTooth protocol has two modes - for the sake of this explanation lets call them: Headset and Headphones

In "Headphones" mode you get:

- Higher quality sound.
- Stereo
- No support for a microphone.
- Often a little bit of lag - you hear the noise slightly later than it would be on a non Bluetooth device.

In "Headset" mode you get:

- Lower quality sound.
- Only Mono output - both sides have the same audio.
- Microphone support.
- Less/very little lag

---

Windows typically exposes the two modes as two different devices, per your screen shot they are called:

- Headphones (WH-1000XM4 Stereo)
- Headset (WH-1000XM4 Hands-Free)

Every BlueTooth headset I have used (regardless of brand) has forced me to pick one of the devices, so I either get Stereo or the Microphone (not both).

So the answer to the original question is stop using "Headphones (WH-1000XM4 Stereo)" and only use "Headset (WH-1000XM4 Hands-Free)" that will allow you to use the Mic, but at the cost of only having low quality mono sound.

---

Side note for Mac users - Mac only exposes a single device, most of the time you get the "Headphones" Stereo mode, but as soon as an app starts using the Mic the Mac switches the Headphones into "Headset" mode, so the sound quality drops - in short its not really any better - it's just that the switch happens automatically for you.