Windows 11 - Doesn't show Hands-free option when connect a bluetooth headset
I've bought a bluetooth headset and tried to connect in a Lenovo Laptop with Windows 11.
The fact is that it works perfectly to listen songs and videos, but when enter in an application that uses the mic (like Zoom or Google Meet), the mic works but I can't hear anything.
So I checked the audio devices and Windows 11 doesn't shows an options to select as output a Hands-free device (just headphone). See the picture below (in PT-BR).
print-sounddevices
--
I tried to use in my personal laptop (Asus with Windows 10) and it works perfectly, showing the hands-free option on the output devices. When in an application that uses the mic, I've selected the Hands-free device. When listening music I've selected the headphone option of the same bluetooth device to improve the sound quality.
On the Windows 11 laptop:
I've already checked the Device Setting and in it's Bluetooth Services was with the "Hands-free" option enabled.
Could someone give me some instructions to fix it?

Dup of: https://superuser.com/questions/1813982/why-isnt-the-computer-detecting-the-microphone-in-a-set-of-sony-headphones/1813986 same underlying cause different symptom (output vs input not working).
